# tongue image opendata

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, uses-of-open-data, open-definition, deep-learning

I am looking for tongue image & photos.
To be precise,
(1) Tongue with glossitis
(2) Tongue with dry mouth
(3) Tongue with tongue cancer
(4) Tongue with a lot of white coating

Even if I google it, there are limits. I would like to ask if anyone knows where opendata is located.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Wikimedia Commons has hundreds of open images of tongues:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Tongues

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Human_tongue

Merit:

- They are open-licensed (most images you found via Google Images are not).

Demerits:

- Most might not match your purpose.
- You will need to label them manually.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
However, there are only about 50 tongue pictures on Wikimedia, which is very limited.

Is there a place where there are more photos?

Answer (score 0):

Besides Wikimedia Commons (already mentioned in @NicolasRaoul's answer, +1), **[Open-i](https://openi.nlm.nih.gov)** offers many medical images, including photographs of tongues. Here's an example of a request you can use (caution, these photographs are of medical nature, so viewing discretion is advised): https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/gridquery?q=tongue&it=xg,ph&m=1&n=100. You can refine the keywords as you wish, as well as the filters (license, type of image, etc.).

The US National Cancer Institute also has a search engine where you can look for images or photographs using specific keywords, you can find many photographs of tongues there, using adequate keywords: **https://visualsonline.cancer.gov/**

Same thing for the US Public Health Image Library: **https://phil.cdc.gov/**

You'll probably have to classify these images yourself, and make sure you're respecting their license.